# Select first of type excluding a div.class

Tags: css

How can I match the first div except if the first div is `div.error`?

```
    <div>
            <div class="error">
                <p>Error 1.</p>
                <p>Error 2.</p>
            </div>

            <div> <!--I want to tag this-->
                Content
            </div>
            <div>
                Content
            </div>
            <div>
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
```

My attempts:

```
div > div:first-of-type:not(.error) {color:red}

div > div[class]:not(.error):first-of-type {color:red}
```

The div.error could appear or not (depending if there are errors or not), so I can't use something like `nth-of-type(2)`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, but it sounds like javascript could solve your problem

Comment: I want to match the div with the comment "I want to tag this"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combination of two selectors. Check the demo to test both situations:

```css
div > div.error:first-of-type + div,
div > div:not(.error):first-of-type {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="error">
        <p>Error 1.</p>
        <p>Error 2.</p>
    </div>
    <div><!-- Should match this-->Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
    <div><!-- Should match this -->Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works nice, but I'm a bit confused with the code. Why this sentence 'div:not(.error):first-of-type' works if there are no errors, and not when there are? It isn't supposed to be to work in both cases? I think that sentence means: "tag the first div which isn't 'error'"

Comment: `div > div:not(.error):first-of-type` works if the first-of-type div has no class `error`. If `div:first-of-type` does have a class `error` this rule doesn't match and is not applied. Instead `div > div.error:first-of-type + div` works, which means get the next div after the first-of-type div with the class `error`.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main div:first-child:not(.error),.main div.error+div{color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="main">
            <div class="error">
                <p>Error 1.</p>
                <p>Error 2.</p>
            </div>

            <div> <!--I want to tag this-->
                Content :: red
            </div>
            <div>
                Content
            </div>
            <div>
                Content
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="main">
            

            <div> <!--I want to tag this-->
                Content :: red
            </div>
            <div>
                Content
            </div>
            <div>
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please, can you explain what 'div:first-child:not(".error")' does? I'm trying your code but doesn't seems to work if there are no error div...